# Set ImagePickerController object to AVCaptureDeviceInput

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod

I am using ImagePickerController for Video Capturing. I need to save the capturing video as image also . So I choose AVCaptureSession for capturing Images. I con't able run the AVCaptureSession as well as ImagePickerController. So I need to give the ImagePickerController as Input to the AVCaptureSession. But I don't know how to do that. Please Help me.. and suggest me for the right way.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: yes... I need to save the video as well as images... Or is there any other way to convert a video into images as soon as possible?....